# Java: JButton actionListener explantation

Tags: java, swing, interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I am extremely confused as to how a `JButton` works.  I have read over the oracle documents of the [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html), but I have failed to see how a JButton can have an actionlistener added to it.  I have really always wondered how things like JFrames and all that can have things like `.addMouseListener` and all that.  Can anyone explain how a `JButton` can have an actionListener added to it like the `.addActionListener(...)` syntax?

My reason for wanting to know how to do this is to create my own "JButton" per say which can have an actionListener added to it and it will fire events when needed.  Is this even possible or no?

Comment: Read up on the observer design pattern since it's all based on that.

Comment: This link might also be helpful for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: So does a JButton implement the actionListener?  And that is how it works? Sorry if I'm being confusing. I am rather confused myself.  Thanks for the link though Sujay, I am reading through it now

EDIT: Wait, abstract buttons do not implement actionListener... then how do buttons get an actionlistener added to them?

Comment: No, the JButton doesn't implement ActionListener. It holds an array of all the ActionListeners added to it and notifies all of the listeners when it is pressed. Another thing that has helped me was to open the source code (here you'd look at AbstractButton's source) to see what happens, what the internal workings are doing.

Comment: the implementation of the actionlistener is actually in the abstractbutton.java file... the code doesn't make much sense to me at the moment but I'll figure it out eventually...

Comment: The key method in AbstractButton is `fireActionPerformed(...)`. In this method, all of the ActionListeners held by the event list are notified by creating an ActionEvent object and calling their `actionPerformed(...)` methods, passing the ActionEvent object in as their parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you have to do to understand the architecture. First the Design pattern used here is the Observer Pattern -

> Implementing the Publisher/Subscriber scenario. We need a mechanism
> which allows us to notify subscriber objects whenever the publisher
> object changes state.

You can find more information about implementing it at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47948/The-Observer-Design-Pattern).

But if your objective is to make your own JButton the best approach is to Subclass JButton.

```
class MyCustomButton extends JButton{}
```

You asked about how `JFrame` can have `addMouseListener` - It's because `JFrame` extends `java.awt.Component`. Hope this helps.

### EDIT

Observer doesn't do anything. Subject notify the Observers if anything change. This is the notify method.

```
 public void notify()
      {
        for (int i=0;i < observers.size();i++)
        {
          Observer ob = (Observer)observers.get(i);
          ob.update(newValue);
        }
      }
```

Back again to the Packet and the Bucket example -
Packet - Observer
Bucket - Subject

Bucket wires the Packet that a new Packet has entered the Bucket. In classes Bucket class will call the notify method and all the registered Packets will be notified. If a Packet wishes to unsubscribe itself from the Bucket it just needs to call the Unsubscribe method and it will remove the Object from the ArrayList of the Bucket.

Comment: Thanks.  I already tried making a subclass of the JButton and it works fine.  I was really curious of how I could possibly make my own type of button which actually worked separately from the JButton component.  I think that is actually what the link you posted was though, so I will check that out now.  Thanks for the help

Comment: OHHHHHHHH! I get it now! It all implements an interface which contains all the methods which can then store all the listeners added to a certain component such as a JButton.  Then it can run through all the listeners and that is where it gets foggy for me...

Comment: Yep... It's something like a bucket. You can add packet to the bucket and the bucket informs all the packets in the bucket that another packet was added... Hope you understood... If Helpful mark the Answer as Correct so it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Ok, one more question and I'll approve the answer.  In the article you sent me, I understand everything except the part where the observer is notified.  What action does the observer take? Isn't it just an interface which cannot actually do anything?

Comment: Its fine but ya I got it thanks I finally understand how all this works